# ExpectModal is not woking with empty caption

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

Can someone help me how to test messagebox with empty caption using ExpectModal?

Message box is closed automatically if  message box has caption  but if the caption is empty ok button is not clicked

sample code:

```
ExpectModal("","MessageBoxOkHandler);
MessageBox.Show("test","",MessageBoxbutton.OK,MessageBoxIcon.warning) 
 public void MessageBoxOkHandler()
        {
            MessageBoxTester messageBox = new MessageBoxTester("");
             messageBox.ClickOK();
}
```

Comment: ExpectModal is an NUnitForms method, not an NUnit method. If you label your question correctly there's a better chance of an answer.

Comment: NunitForms is not available in existing tag. I tried to add Nunitform to the tag but I got error  .That's the reason I used Nunit in my label.

Comment: I tagged if for you. BTW I'm listed as a contributor to nunitforms but haven't done anything for a long time. In fact, it hasn't been updated for about 7 years. One suggestion: Make sure you are using the version of NUnit supported by your version of NUnitForms.

Comment: I have referred the nunit.framework.dll and nunitforms.dll and added the corrsponding namespace in the application.  But the ExpectModal functiin is not available for me. I am not able to and the nunit.extensions.forms.nunitformstest namespace to my application.   I have installed nunitforms v 2. Please  help me some suggestion to aolve thos issue.